# os.system argument from config file

Tags: python, configparser, os.system

I made this activity and it works. I need to have config file with USB/VID/PID.

```
def resetactivity():
        os.system(r'"devcon.exe restart "*USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321*"')
```

I try to do this with config parser. I made config.txt:

```
[My Section]
usbdev = r'"devcon.exe restart "*USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321*"'
```

I read my config file in Python:

```py
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.txt')
usbdev = config.get('My Section', 'usbdev')
```

And when I am trying to use this in os.system command like this:

```
def resetactivity():
        os.system(usbdev)
```

I get this result:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
> 'PID_3321*"'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Place a "print(usbdev)" above the "os.system" call to see what is actually given to "os.system".

Comment: You have mismatched quotes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it prints correct  r'"devcon.exe restart "*USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321*"'

Comment: Running unsanitized, arbitrary code directly from a config file sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: You have too many quotes. You wouldn't type `"devcon.exe restart ..."` at the command line, but `devcon.exe restart "..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
import configparser
import os

def resetactivity():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.txt')
    usbdev = config.get('My Section', 'usbdev')
    print(usbdev)
    os.system(usbdev)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    resetactivity()
```

With **config.txt** formatted as

```
[My Section] 
usbdev = devcon.exe restart "USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321"
```

Comment: My result now is: r'devcon.exe restart "USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321"'
'r'devcon.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you make sure that devcon.exe is available on PATH? if so then let me know (If devcon.exe is available at path this error will go away or run the script where devcon.exe is present in the directory)

Comment: devcon.exe is in the same folder which my main.py is.  Now is working.  My config txt is now [My Section]
usbdev = devcon.exe restart "*USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321*"  and my activity is def resetactivity():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.txt')
    usbdev = config.get('My Section', 'usbdev')
    print(usbdev)
    os.system(usbdev)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    resetactivity()

Comment: [My Section] 
usbdev = r'devcon.exe restart "USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321"' use this config

Comment: I found a solution. I need to set my config to [My Section]
usbdev = devcon.exe restart "*USB\VID_04E8&PID_3321*"  but i don't know why it's working without r'

Comment: The reason is the config file doesn't have the python syntax it is a text file that gets parsed to obtain the right information. I rarely use the config files like this instead I use JSON files as configuration files in python programs since chances of mistake happening like this with JSON are slim. (It is available as json in python3)